# Docker image of 32 bit Ubuntu

Tags: docker

1. I am looking a lightweight docker image with Ubuntu 32 bit. Where can I find it?
2. When I put a command `docker build .` in my directory with Dockerfile I get output like:

> ```
> ending build context to Docker daemon 10.21 MB
>  Step 1 : FROM ubuntu
>   ---> 104bec311bcd
>  Step 2 : ENV x /home/
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> e38b022c91f8
>  Step 3 : COPY ./x /home
>   ---> Using cache
>   ---> c4558c94236f
> ```

What does those "hashes" means? I mean for example `c4558c94236f`. And what about when it comes to cache?

Comment: Probably it's using an existent image (Ubuntu) and the hash is a layer of that (latest). Run `docker images -a` and see if you find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find in the Docker Hub various 32 bits docker images, for example

https://hub.docker.com/r/32bit/ubuntu/

You can learn how to do it yourself with

http://mwhiteley.com/linux-containers/2013/08/31/docker-on-i386.html

About the hashes, you should read

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Comment: use this in a Google search to find many more 32 bits docker images `site:hub.docker.com "32 bits"`