# Install Neo4j with Docker

Tags: docker, neo4j

I have been worrying all day about installing Neo4j with Docker and that Neo4J opens on the localhost port 7474. I followed a lot of tutorials, I looked at the error messages but I have not found any answers for the moment. I hope you will be able to join me please.

I am on Linux Mint, docker is install on my PC and I use the following command to install Neo4J:

```
docker run \
--publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
neo4j:3.0
```

Here is my error message:

> Unable to find image 'neo4j:latest' locally latest: Pulling from
>   library/neo4j docker: no matching manifest for linux/386 in the
>   manifest list entries. See 'docker run --help'.

I launch the order by being sudo but unsuccessful.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Docker has issues running on 32bit machines as some images are not compatible. Running your command on a 64bit machine, no errors will be thrown.
Further information will be found at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41677104/7719775)